# Is there a "Facebook Search API" similar to the "Twitter Search API"?

Tags: facebook, search, twitter

I need to search Facebook for certain keywords and count them if possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not cover everything you want, but the new Graph API does, indeed, [include search](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#search).